# How to add nginx modules on windows platforme?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to test Streaming media files in my local Nginx configuration.
I need to add two nginx modules : flv and mp4

--with-http_flv_module for Flash Video (FLV) files 
 --with-http_mp4_module for H.264/AAC files

however, I'm using Kevin Worthington install : http://kevinworthington.com/nginx-for-windows/, so I'm not eable to add thoses modules in order to check if Nginx sends partial-content 206 header when requesting Streaming media.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this link, to building nginx on the Win32 platform with Visual C : http://nginx.org/en/docs/howto_build_on_win32.html